# Can not change/replace NSDictionary Key value IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, plist, nsdictionary

I am downloading a file revision status from Dropbox and basically I compare downloaded revison number in Dropbox with revision number in my local plist.

After comparing them I want to change local revision number with Dropbox's revision number. But it is not working I am about to loss my mind.

I put some flags and NSlogs it seems it replace the value but after I call same function or launch the app again I see that value is not replaced. It gives the same output over and over again

```
    NSString* revisionLocal = [dicInner objectForKey:@"revision"];
    NSString* statusLocal = [dicInner objectForKey:@"status"];

    NSLog(@"revision  value before %@",revisionLocal);
    NSLog(@"status value before %@",statusLocal);

   //If revision has changed on dropbox, flag it as outdated on the local revision
                        if(![revisionLocal isEqualToString: dropBoxRevision] ){
                            [dicInner setValue:@"outdated" forKey:@"status"];
                            //But the revision is the latest
                            [dicInner setValue:dropBoxRevision forKey:@"revision"];
                            //[dicInner setValue:@"outdated" forKey:@"revision"];

                            NSLog(@"revision value %@",[dicInner objectForKey:@"revision"]);
                            NSLog(@"status value %@",[dicInner objectForKey:@"status"]);
```

so this give me the output of:

```
revision  value before 4309efbbb7
status value before updated
revision value 4409efbbb7
status value outdated
```

And the full code is:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata {

    //get the local revision
    NSDictionary * localRevisionDic = [FileUtils readPlistIntoDictionary:@"revision.plist"];

    NSString *fileRevString = [NSString alloc];
    //get the revision from Dropbox
    //NSString * dropboxRevision;
    if (metadata.isDirectory) { 
        NSLog(@"Folder '%@' contains:", metadata.path);
        for (DBMetadata *file in metadata.contents) {

            NSLog(@"\t%@", file.filename);
            //NSLog(@"\t%@", file.lastModifiedDate);
            NSLog(@"\t%@", file.rev ); 

            //Assign dropbox revision for this file
            //dropboxRevision = file.rev;
            //if no local revision.plist, entry will be added. Hence init here
            if (localRevisionDic==nil){
                localRevisionDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

            }
            //Otherwise go through each from dropbox and campare with local

            //From Dropbox
            NSString * dropBoxFileName = file.filename;
            NSString * dropBoxRevision = file.rev;

            fileRevString = file.rev;

            //if no local revision.plist entry is added for all other files
            //with status need_downloaded, and no revision
            if ([localRevisionDic count]==0){

                //Creating revision dictionary entry for agenda.plist
                NSDictionary * localRevisionDicDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                //when agenda.plist revision entry is added update the revision while leaving status as "new" before downloading
                //will be updated accordingly if download fails
                [localRevisionDicDic setValue:@"new" forKey:@"status"];
                //Status is new but the revision is the latest
                [localRevisionDicDic setValue:dropBoxRevision forKey:@"revision"];

                [localRevisionDic setValue:localRevisionDicDic forKey:dropBoxFileName];

            }else{//If there is local revision.plist compare and update accordingly
                NSDictionary * dicInner = [localRevisionDic objectForKey:dropBoxFileName];
                //File name Found locally
                if (dicInner!=nil){
                    NSString* revisionLocal = [dicInner objectForKey:@"revision"];
                    NSString* statusLocal = [dicInner objectForKey:@"status"];

                    NSLog(@"revision  value before %@",revisionLocal);
                    NSLog(@"status value before %@",statusLocal);

                    //If revision has changed on dropbox, flag it as outdated on the local revision
                    if(![revisionLocal isEqualToString: dropBoxRevision] ){
                        [dicInner setValue:@"outdated" forKey:@"status"];
                        //But the revision is the latest
                        [dicInner setValue:dropBoxRevision forKey:@"revision"];
                        //[dicInner setValue:@"outdated" forKey:@"revision"];

                        NSLog(@"revision value %@",[dicInner objectForKey:@"revision"]);
                        NSLog(@"status value %@",[dicInner objectForKey:@"status"]);
                    }
                    }else{//File name not found locally newly added on dropbox

                        NSDictionary * localRevisionDicDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                        //when agenda.plist revision entry is added update the revision while leaving status as "new" before downloading
                        //will be updated accordingly if download fails
                        [localRevisionDicDic setValue:@"new" forKey:@"status"];
                        //But the revision is the latest
                        [localRevisionDicDic setValue:dropBoxRevision forKey:@"revision"];

                        [localRevisionDic setValue:localRevisionDicDic forKey:dropBoxFileName];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //At this point agendaRevisionDicTemp contains all the files in dropbox entered/updated.
    [[self agenda] setRevision:localRevisionDic];

    //*****The following block is needed to determine is new agenda is needed or not.
    BOOL newAgendaNeeded = false;

    NSMutableDictionary * agendaRevisionDicLocal = [localRevisionDic objectForKey:@"agenda.plist"];

    //NSString * localRevision = [agendaRevisionDicLocal objectForKey:@"revision"]; //what is this value?

    NSString * localStatus = [agendaRevisionDicLocal objectForKey:@"status"];
    NSLog(@"Local Status= %@",agendaRevisionDicLocal);


    if ([localStatus isEqualToString:@"new"] ||[localStatus isEqualToString:@"outdated"]){
        newAgendaNeeded = true;
        //when agenda.plist is added update the revision while leaving status as "new" before downloading
        //will be updated accordingly if download fails
        NSDictionary * agendaDic = [[[self agenda]revision] objectForKey:@"agenda.plist"];
        [agendaDic setValue:@"updated" forKey:@"status"];
        NSLog(@"agendaDic where update %@",agendaDic);

    }
    //*****The above block is needed to determine is new agenda is needed or not.

    //If new agenda is needed download
    if (newAgendaNeeded){
        //Download agenda.plist
        NSString *documentsDirectory = FileUtils.getDocumentsDirectory;
        [[self restClient] loadFile:@"/agenda.plist" intoPath: [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectory,@"agenda.plist"] ];

    } else{//Else display the scene

        [self populateSceneFromAgenda];

    }

    [restOfView reloadData];
    // Add at start of requestFinished AND requestFailed
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
}
```

Any Idea How Can I replace that value?

Comment: You should really not call a NSMutableDictionary an NSDictionary! `NSDictionary * localRevisionDicDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]...`

Comment: when I alloc and set all of them NSMutable I get `incompatible` types warning but this way I get now warnings

Comment: Above comment is right about the immutable dictionary but what I wonder is where do you set `[[self agenda] setRevision:localRevisionDic];` method could you jump the definition ?

Comment: could you also put a flag there and see your values are really inside of dictionary?

Comment: @SpaceDust it is all there 14 pairs they are changed but plist didnt save the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your dictionary changes correctly whats wrong with your code should be that you do not save your dictionary to the plist you edit

In fact there is deffinetly something wrong with that method`[[self agenda] setRevision:localRevisionDic];`

Try to add following code below from `[[self agenda] setRevision:localRevisionDic];`

```
//write dictionary to plist 
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"revision.plist"];
    // write plist to disk
    [localRevisionDic writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

    // read it back in with different dictionary variable
    NSMutableDictionary *savedStock = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
    if( savedStock==nil ){
        NSLog(@"failed to retrieve dictionary from disk");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't respect immutability of your NSDictionary objects. You declare localRevisionDic as NSDictionary*, but later it could be assigned value of NSMutableDictionary. localRevisionDicDic declared as NSDictionary* but initialised with value of NSMutableDictionary. Following two assignments should be warned at compile time. At line

```
[localRevisionDic setValue:localRevisionDicDic forKey:dropBoxFileName];
```

who knows for sure is localRevisionDic mutable or immutable one?
Then, again, you declare dicInner as NSDictionary*, but try to setValue twice later. Make mutableCopy of dictionary first.